# Git deattached HEAD using synchronizing from GitHub client

Tags: git, github, git-merge, github-for-windows

I'm experiencing the following issue using Git:

1. I forked a repository in GitHub
2. I cloned the repository to local using the GitHub client
3. Other developer commited to GitHub in branch master
4. I locally commit to my local git repo (so I'm getting out of sync, the commit was an unsynced commit)

When **I use the command line** to resolve this:

```
 git pull -> merge detected
 git mergetool -> resolve conflicts
 git commit -m "Reolved conflicts"
 git push -> All changes were uploaded to GitHub
```

All worked smoothly. However **when I use the GitHub client**, the following happens:

> 1. Press sync to resolve the conflics.
> 2. GitHub says that there is a merge pending to resolve
> 3. Inmediatly my local repo is in **deattached HEAD**

Please, someone could explain why the GitHub client is leaving my repo in deattached head?

Comment: I had the same problem once, but I honestly don't remember how I got it working. Anyway, after much struggle

Comment: Yes, you can create a branch to move the pending changes, and then merge to master, but is a very complicated workflow. What I want to know is if this behavior is a bug in the GitHub client.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm trying to remember, but it's been some time since, and I was just getting started with git (not that now I would master it). I'll give an answer if, by chance, I remember anything. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github for Windows would do a rebase I believe. If there are conflicts and you see that you are in detached head state, try resolving the conflicts, `git add` the resolved files if needed, and do

```
git rebase --continue.
```

To understand more see what `git pull --rebase` does over just `git pull`